# Header view that contracts when scrolled away

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want a big view at the top of my table. This provides search parameters like a search bar, but with more options… and, thus, taking much more space. (Let's say 100 pixels.)

As I scroll it off, I want it to *not* disappear but just simplify. (Let's say 44 pixels.) Instead of a editable fields, it would become a summary of the search. Tapping that summary would scroll back to the top, expanding the search view to its full size again.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is that your header should not be a part of your `UITableView`, but added on the same level.

```
[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
[self.view addSubview:self.myHeaderView];
```

To make the table behave normally, just put an empty header on the table (`tableView.tableHeaderView`) of the same size as the view you need.

```
UIView *emptyHeader = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.myHeaderView.bounds];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = emptyHeader;
```

Also, since the behaviour of your custom header is dynamic, you are gonna have to make a `UIView` subclass and manage your header there.

Have your `UITableViewDelegate` implement the `scrollViewDidScroll`, and check the contentOffset every time it's called.

Say your expanded view's height is 100, and 44 when contracted:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > (100 - 44)) {
        // Contract your header
        myHeaderView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44);
        [myHeaderView contract]; // Make it display whatever data you want and setup the touch gesture
    }
    else {
        int offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
        // The reason for the -offset is that you need it to align to the table's real header position, which will be a little off screen
        myHeaderView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -offset, self.view.frame.size.width, 100);
        [myHeaderView expand];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Indeed. I think that should do it. Do you have any suggestions for the appearance of the search between 44 and 100? I was thinking shrinking the 100 pixel image appropriately and fading from one to the other might be appropriate. That might be too costly, though?

Comment: You could have 2 subviews inside there, one for the enlarged version and one for the smaller version, and just fade one in while fading the other out, but idk, I'm no UX or VD magician :)